# Kernel panic: not syncing fatal machine check after upgrading the system

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, arch-linux, bootloader

I recently upgraded my system from AMD FX 8320 (with DDR3 RAM and M5A97 mobo) to Intel i7-9700K (with DDR4 RAM and a z-390 mobo).

I have 2 different SSDs, one with Windows 10 installation and another with archlinux. After the said upgrade, I am able to boot into Windows without any issues, however the EFI bootloader does not list the drive with archlinux. Using a trial version of [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/), I added an entry for my archlinux installation to the UEFI firmware bootloader.

So far, so good. I understand that my GPT id's would have changed, and the boot might fail horribly, but I anticipated that it should atleast fallback to a rescue shell.

I boot into the newly created/restored arch entry, select my linux for boot and it fails with different messages related to kernel panic (screenshots below).

[image: x]

[image: y]

I also tried creating a USB bootable to check if I can recreate my `fstab`, but the bootable drive also fails with a **microcode udev** error.

Any ideas on how to cleanup my boot configuration for the arch bootloader?

---

Following the steps from comment by @VarunNarravula:

> I tried creating a bootable from the windows machine itself.
>   Downloaded arch-netinstall bootable iso, created a flash drive using
>   unetbootin, and when I reboot to the usb interface, it also fails with
>   similar messages.

Comment: I would say make an arch linux bootable from another computer, preferably one with an Intel x86_64 processor similar to the one you installed, and booting into your broken system using that. Chroot into this, and compiling a new kernel may solve it, because your kernel is still the one from before you switched CPUs. So you may want to recompile a kernel with support for Intel microcode; possibly that is what is causing the “processor context corrupt” and “microcode udev” errors.

Comment: @VarunNarravula I tried creating a bootable from the windows machine itself. Downloaded arch-netinstall bootable iso, created a flash drive using unetbootin, and when I reboot to the usb interface, it also fails with similar messages.

Comment: Ok so you used the same Windows installation prior to switching out the CPU and mobo, right? Then try reinstalling Windows on the same computer/hard drive, then creating the bootable from that installation. Either your firmware is buggy or Windows isn’t creating the installation media for Arch Linux right.

Comment: I doubt that that is how a bootable device is supposed to work @VarunNarravula

Comment: Well what application are you using for creating it?

Comment: @VarunNarravula [unetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/)

Comment: Try using Rufus. May do the job better than unetbootin. Make sure it’s GPT and UEFI (non CSM) on Rufus before writing the ISO image, and instead of creating a custom NVRAM entry for Arch Linux, try moving up the USB to the top of the boot order and let it boot automatically. Then you should install a proper boot manager, which boots the kernel a lot better than your standard UEFI firmware (I recommend rEFInd, you can install this from the default pacman repos, called refind-efi)

Comment: @VarunNarravula creating a bootable w/ rufus worked. Configured my intel-ucode image and booted into arch currently. Thanks. You can compile this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you replace your computer’s crucial hardware like your CPU, usually a reinstallation is Windows solves it for UNetbootin. Besides, a periodic reinstallation for Windows always solves things with Windows. But don’t use UNetbootin, it only configures hardware support for the machine Windows was initially installed on. Use [Rufus](http://rufus.ie).

When you use Rufus instead, it uses the current Windows kernel, unlike UNetbootin. So any Linux ISOs imaged onto a USB should work because the image now reflects the different microcode used in the CPU.